# How to set upper limit in Generics comparison

Tags: java, generics

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T secondSmallestGeneric(List<T> list) {
        T smallest = list.get(0);  // ** buggy
        T secondSmallest = null;
        for(T each : list) {
            if(each.compareTo(smallest) < 0) {
                secondSmallest = smallest;
                smallest = each;
            }else if(secondSmallest != null && each.compareTo(secondSmallest) < 0) {
                secondSmallest = each;
            }
        }
        if(secondSmallest != null)
            return secondSmallest;
        return null;
    }
```

Issue: If the fist entry in the list contains the least.
In the case of Comparing numbers, I used Integer.MAX_VALUE; to set an upper bound.
But here, I am working with custom classes.

Comment: If all items of type `T` are sortable, just sort the list and pick the first two elements.

Comment: I just ran your code with a list of integers and it worked.

Comment: I followed your first comment and did it in another way, `list.stream().distinct().sorted().limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList()).get(1);`

instead of picking the the element out of a list, one could also skip by using `skip` while streaming

Comment: The important thing here is that you figured it out. Good job! I'm glad I was able to help you do that.